# Writing the function to get even numbers from an array and append them to a different array in Python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Need to write a function which takes a dynamic array as variables. The function then checks for all even numbers in the array and appends those even numbers to a different array. Also any help on the time for computing this code would be appreciated.

I have defined a function and initiated an array. I am trying do it in Numpy. I tried reading on any() and all() but don't know how to implement it as I want to perform an iterative loop with appending.

```
def even(x):
        b = []
        a = [x]
        for x in a:
            if x % 2 == 0:
                b = b.append(x)
                next 
arr1 = np.arange(10,51)
even(arr1)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-302372375b1e> in <module>
      7                 next
      8 arr1 = np.arange(10,51)
----> 9 even(arr1)

<ipython-input-10-302372375b1e> in even(x)
      3         a = [x]
      4         for x in a:
----> 5             if x % 2 == 0:
      6                 b = b.append(x)
      7                 next

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Don't understand the first error output's meaning. For the second one I do understand that the array output is boolean and therefore need to use any or all. However, what I want is that the output of array a be integer number and if it meets the for criteria of even then it gets added to array b.

Edit: Thanks for the answers all of you. Definitely helps with the solution. However, just a minor query, if someone could explain what is the meaning of the first error.

I am learning python and this is for educational purposes.

Comment: Try `arr1[arr1 % 2 == 0]` - it will give you all the even numbers. [Boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html?highlight=array#boolean-array-indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code is that numpy arrays broadcast; `x % 2 == 0` will evaluate to an array:

```
[ True False  True False  ... True]
```

which does not evaluate to a simple `bool` in your `if` statement: `bool(arr1 % 2 == 0)` will rasie the `ValueError` you got.

instead of your function you could just use [boolean or 'mask' indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.arange(10, 51)
res = arr1[arr1 % 2 == 0]
# [10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50]
```

Comment: Won't that return **all** the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python filter function and simplify your function definition as follows

```
def get_even(arr1):
    return np.array(list(filter(lambda x:x%2==0,arr1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np   

 def even(your_array):
        arr =np.array([n for n in your_array if n % 2 == 0])
```

you can also use the filter function:

```
  def even(your_array):
        return np.array(list(filter(lambda n: n % 2 == 0, your_array)))
```

when you call the function you ll get a new array:

```
arr = even(some_array)
```

Comment: @basilik 
arr =np.array([n for n in your_array if n % 2 == 0])
Can you explain the flow of operational sequencing in this command? This is from the POV of syntax...want to understand how and why 'n for n in....'

Comment: @Rogue258 the syntax is called list Comprehensions, you can google it and you ll find many examples. that basically equals to a Code when you declare an empty array at outer scope for example:
 res = []
 for n in your_array: 
      if n%2==0:  
           res.append(n)
 return res

Answer (score 0):

```
complete_array = [*range(1,21)]
print (complete_array)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
even_array = [i for i in a if i%2==0]
print (f'Required Array: {even_array}')
>>> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Comment: without numpy and with numpy it's simpler:                                                                   
import numpy as np
complete_array = np.arange(1,21)
print (complete_array)

even_array = a[a%2==0]
print (even_array)

Comment: Your commented improvment was also mentioned by "hiro protagonist" years ago and is the accepted answer. There is no need to duplicate answers because this could be difficult to understand for other users.